# Examples when differentiation under the integral sign fails

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, examples-counterexamples

A particular version of Feynman's trick for integration is as follows:

> Let $f(x, t)$ be a function such that both $f(x, t)$ and its partial
> derivative $f_x(x, t)$ are continuous in $t$ and $x$ in some region of
> the $(x, t)$-plane, including $a ≤ t ≤ b$, $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$. Then, for
> $x_0 ≤ x ≤ x_1$, $${\frac {d}{dx}}\left(\int _{a}^{b}f(x,t)\,dt\right)
>  =\int _{a}^{b}{\frac {\partial }{\partial x}}f(x,t)\,dt. \tag{1}
> $$

A more general version is in this [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign). I have seen lots of interesting examples solved by this technique. See for instance [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Applications).

I am curious about "counterexamples" when assumptions of this theorem are not fully satisfied. Specifically, can one come up with an example that *both* sides of (1) exist but the equal sign is not true?

Comment: A cheap example is to take $f$ integrable but not differentiable.

Comment: See [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/105769/counterexamples-to-differentiation-under-integral-sign).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to José Carlos Santos's [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3824762/examples-when-differentiation-under-the-integral-sign-fails?noredirect=1#comment7887889_3824762), I find this interesting related question on MathOverflow: [Counterexamples to differentiation under integral sign?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/105769).

The following are two examples from two answers there.

---

Consider $$f(x,y) = \cases{ \text{sgn}(x) \dfrac{x^2-y^2}{x^2} & for $0 < |y| < |x|$  \cr 0 & otherwise
}$$
Then $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y)\ dy = 4 x/3$ for $-1 \le x \le 1$, so $\displaystyle \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \int_{-1}^1 f(x,y)\ dy = 4/3$,
but $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (0,y) = 0$ so $\displaystyle \int_{-1}^1 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,y)\ dy = 0$.

---

Set
$$
f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^3y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}, & {\rm if} \ x \not= 0 \ {\rm or } \ y \not= 0, \\
0, & {\rm if } \ x = 0 \ {\rm and } \ y = 0, 
\end{cases}
$$
Then the integral
$$
F(x) = \int_0^1 f(x,y)\,{\rm d}y
$$
can be computed to equal $\frac{x}{2(1+x^2)}$ for all $x$ (check $x = 0$ separately). This is a differentiable function for all $x$, with
$$
F'(x) = \frac{1-x^2}{2(1+x^2)^2}.
$$
In particular, $F'(0) = 1/2$. However,
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x^2y(3y^2-x^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}, & {\rm if } \ y \not= 0, \\
0, & {\rm if } \ y = 0, 
\end{cases}
$$
so $f_x(0,y) = 0$. Therefore the "equation"
$$
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}\int_0^1 f(x,y)\,{\rm d}y = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x,y)\,{\rm d}y
$$
is invalid at $x = 0$, where the left side is $1/2$ and the right side is $0$. A problem is that $f_x(x,y)$ is not a continuous function of two variables: along the line $y = x$ we have $f_x(x,y) = f_x(x,x) = 1/(4x)$ for $x \not= 0$, which does not converge as $x \rightarrow 0$ even though $f_x(0,0) = 0$ is defined.